# Display list of objects and set a value field for each input MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-binding

I have the following class defined as my ViewModel

```
 public class CreateApplicationViewModel
    {
        public Step1ViewModel Step1 { get; set; }
        public Step2StandAloneViewModel Step2StandAlone { get; set; }
        public Step2ChildViewModel Step2Child { get; set; }
        public Step3ViewModel Step3 { get; set; }
        public Step4ViewModel Step4 { get; set; }
    }
```

I'm trying to display items in the Step4ViewModel which consists of the following:

```
 public class Step4ViewModel
    {
        public List<DataDetails> DataDetails = new List<DataDetails>();

    }

public class DataDetails
    {
        public string GroupCode { get; set; }
        public string GroupDesc { get; set; }
        public decimal DetailSequence { get; set; }
        public string DetailCode { get; set; }
        public string DetailDesc { get; set; }
        public string YesNoFlag { get; set; }
        public string NumberFlag { get; set; }
        public string ValueFlag { get; set; }
        public string DateFlag { get; set; }
        public string ListValuesFlag { get; set; }
        public string CommentFlag { get; set; }
        public string CalcRateFlag { get; set; }
        public string ColumnSequence { get; set; }
        public string TextFlag { get; set; }
        public string CheckboxFlag { get; set; }
        public string YesNoValue { get; set; }
        public int NumberValue { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateValue { get; set; }
        public string ListValue { get; set; }
        public string CommentValue { get; set; }
        public string TextValue { get; set; }
        public bool CheckboxValue { get; set; }
    }
```

In my controller I populate the Step4ViewModel.DataDetails like so:

```
private Step4ViewModel GetCaseDataDetails(string caseType)
        {
            Step4ViewModel model = new Step4ViewModel();

            List<DataDetails> data = new List<DataDetails>();
            List<DataDetailsValues> values = new List<DataDetailsValues>();

            var dataDetails = (from tb1 in db.DEFAULT_CASE_DATA_VW
                               join tb2 in db.CASE_DATA_DETAIL on tb1.CASE_DATA_GROUP_ID equals tb2.CASE_DATA_GROUP_ID
                               where tb1.BUS_CASE_CODE == caseType
                               orderby tb2.DETAIL_SEQUENCE
                               select new { tb1, tb2 });


            foreach (var detail in dataDetails.ToList())
            {
                DataDetails i = new DataDetails();
                DataDetailsValues j = new DataDetailsValues();
                i.CalcRateFlag = detail.tb2.CALC_RATE_FLAG;
                i.CheckboxFlag = detail.tb2.CHECKBOX_FLAG;
                i.ColumnSequence = detail.tb2.COLUMN_SEQUENCE;
                i.CommentFlag = detail.tb2.COMMENT_FLAG;
                i.DateFlag = detail.tb2.DATE_FLAG;
                i.DetailCode = detail.tb2.DETAIL_CODE;
                i.DetailDesc = detail.tb2.DETAIL_DESC;
                i.DetailSequence = detail.tb2.DETAIL_SEQUENCE;
                i.GroupCode = detail.tb1.GROUP_CODE;
                i.GroupDesc = detail.tb1.GROUP_DESC;
                i.ListValuesFlag = detail.tb2.LIST_VALUES_FLAG;
                i.NumberFlag = detail.tb2.NUMBER_FLAG;
                i.TextFlag = detail.tb2.TEXT_FLAG;
                i.ValueFlag = detail.tb2.VALUE_FLAG;
                i.YesNoFlag = detail.tb2.YES_NO_FLAG;
                data.Add(i);
            }
            model.DataDetails = data;
            return model;
        }
```

My thought process with the Step4ViewModel is that for every DataDetail I will display the DetailDesc as a label and then beside of it I will have an input for the NumberValue, YesOrNoValue, NumberValue, DateValue, ListValue, CommentValue, TextValue, or CheckboxValue depending on the control type and then post that data to server.  I am able to successfully display each DataDetail.DetailDesc, but for each input, which also renders, the values I enter into the inputs never post back to the server.  Here is what my view looks like:

```
@model Portal.Models.ViewModel.CreateApplicationViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Step 4/5";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
@using System.Linq

<h4>Case Data Details</h4>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Step4", "CreateApplication", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "col-sm-12" }))
{

    foreach (var group in Model.Step4.DataDetails.GroupBy(item => item.GroupDesc))
    {
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading">@Html.Encode(group.Key)</div>
            <div class="panel-body">

                @for (var i = 0; i < group.Count(); i++)
                { 
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-6">
                                <label class="form-label">@Model.Step4.DataDetails[i].DetailDesc</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-6">
                                @if (Model.Step4.DataDetails[i].TextFlag == "Y")
                                {
                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(val => Model.Step4.DataDetails[i].TextValue, new { @class = "form-control" })
                                }
                                else if (Model.Step4.DataDetails[i].CheckboxFlag == "Y")
                                {
                                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(val => Model.Step4.DataDetails[i].CheckboxValue, new { @class = "checkbox" })
                                }
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    }
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="row">
            @Html.ActionLink("Cancel", "Welcome", "Home", null, new { @class = "btn btn-default" })
            <button class="btn btn-default" onclick="history.go(-1);">Previous</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Next</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Controller to which post data

```
[HttpPost] 
public ActionResult Step4(Step4ViewModel step4) 
{ 
    if (ModelState.IsValid) 
    { 
        CreateApplicationViewModel model = (CreateApplicationViewModel)Session["case"]; 
        // model.Step4 = step4; 
        Session["case"] = model; 
        return View(); 
    } 
    return View(); 
}
```

I was thinking this could be due the grouping, which I do to separate each group into a separate HTML panel element, but my inputs are rendering with the index number in the name.  Any help or suggestions on a better way to accomplish this would be greatly appreciated.  Cheers!

**UPDATE**

Here is my updated post controller and view:

```
@model Portal.Models.ViewModel.CreateApplicationViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Step 4/5";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
@using System.Linq

<h4>Case Data Details</h4>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Step4", "CreateApplication", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "col-sm-12" }))
{

    int index = 0;
    foreach (var group in Model.Step4.DataDetails.GroupBy(item => item.GroupDesc))
    {
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading">@Html.Encode(group.Key)</div>
            <div class="panel-body">

                <input type="hidden" name="Step4.DataDetails.Index" value="@index" />

                @for (var i = 0; i < group.Count(); i++)
                {
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-6">
                                <label class="form-label">@Model.Step4.DataDetails[i].DetailDesc</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-6">
                                @if (Model.Step4.DataDetails[i].TextFlag == "Y")
                                {
                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(val => val.Step4.DataDetails[i].TextValue, new { @class = "form-control" })
                                }
                                else if (Model.Step4.DataDetails[i].CheckboxFlag == "Y")
                                {
                                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(val => val.Step4.DataDetails[i].CheckboxValue, new { @class = "checkbox" })
                                }
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                }
            </div>
        </div>
        index++;
    }
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="row">
            @Html.ActionLink("Cancel", "Welcome", "Home", null, new { @class = "btn btn-default" })
            <button class="btn btn-default" onclick="history.go(-1);">Previous</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Next</button>
        </div>
    </div>
}


[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Step4(CreateApplicationViewModel step4)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                CreateApplicationViewModel model = (CreateApplicationViewModel)Session["case"];
               // model.Step4 = step4;
                Session["case"] = model;
                return View();
            }
            return View();
        }
```

**UPDATE 2**

I am able to get the form input if I pass a FormCollection to the HttpPost controller.  Any ideas as to why I can get these values as a FormCollection but not as the model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the model back to the controller by taking the idea of using an index integer and incrementing it from the answer above and implementing the idea in a different way in my view:

```
@model Portal.Models.ViewModel.CreateApplicationViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Step 4/5";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
@using System.Linq

<h4>Case Data Details</h4>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Step4", "CreateApplication", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "col-sm-12" }))
{
    int index = 0;
    foreach (var group in Model.Step4.DataDetails.GroupBy(item => item.GroupDesc))
    {

        <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading">@Html.Encode(group.Key)</div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                @for (var i = 0; i < group.Count(); i++)
                {
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-6">
                                <label class="form-label">@Model.Step4.DataDetails[i].DetailDesc</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-6">
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(val => val.Step4.DataDetails[index].TextValue)
                                @Html.HiddenFor(val => val.Step4.DataDetails[index].GroupCode)
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    index++;
                }

            </div>
        </div>
    }
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="row">
            @Html.ActionLink("Cancel", "Welcome", "Home", null, new { @class = "btn btn-default" })
            <button class="btn btn-default" onclick="history.go(-1);">Previous</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Next</button>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

The above code in the view gives me the proper index of every element and allows me to post

Answer (score 0):

You are posting list of complex objects. But MVC `DefaultModelBinder` can’t able to bind to your `DataDetails` object because Index must be in sequence when posting the form with list of complex objects. In your case due to nested for loop, this sequence is broken. So what you can do is take one separate variable and initialize with default 0 value like this - I have tried to modify your code.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Step4", "CreateApplication", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "col-sm-12" }))
{

    int index = 0;
    foreach (var group in Model.Step4.DataDetails.GroupBy(item => item.GroupDesc))
    {
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading">@Html.Encode(group.Key)</div>
            <div class="panel-body">

                <input type="hidden" name="Step4.DataDetails.Index" value="@index" />

                @for (var i = 0; i < group.Count(); i++)
                { 
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-6">
                                <label class="form-label">@Model.Step4.DataDetails[i].DetailDesc</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-6">
                                @if (Model.Step4.DataDetails[i].TextFlag == "Y")
                                {
                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(val => val.Step4.DataDetails[i].TextValue, new { @class = "form-control" })
                                }
                                else if (Model.Step4.DataDetails[i].CheckboxFlag == "Y")
                                {
                                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(val => val.Step4.DataDetails[i].CheckboxValue, new { @class = "checkbox" })
                                }
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                }
            </div>
        </div>
        index++;
    }
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="row">
            @Html.ActionLink("Cancel", "Welcome", "Home", null, new { @class = "btn btn-default" })
            <button class="btn btn-default" onclick="history.go(-1);">Previous</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Next</button>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Look at the hidden field i have added in the view. That do the trick to post your data even with the broken sequences. Hope this help you.

Comment: First, thank you for the reply.  I tried out the code above and my model is still has a count of 0 when posting back to the server.  Here is my post controller:

    `[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Step4(Step4ViewModel step4)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                CreateApplicationViewModel model = (CreateApplicationViewModel)Session["case"];
               // model.Step4 = step4;
                Session["case"] = model;
                return View();
            }
            return View();
        }`

Comment: I attempted to render the list to the view without the nested for but the model still doesn't post to the server.

Comment: @ghoston3rd: In your `Step4` action method, change your argument from `Step4ViewModel` to pass whole model -  `CreateApplicationViewModel`. So post this model instead of `Step4ViewModel`. Mvc post data to controller based on your render control name. So your code - `@Html.TextBoxFor(val => val.Step4.DataDetails[i].TextValue, new { @class = "form-control" })` render with as per the model name.

Comment: @ghoston3rd: Check out my blog article regarding this situation - [ASP.NET MVC: Post a list or collection of complex types with non-sequential indices](https://krishnrajrana.wordpress.com/2015/12/15/asp-net-mvc-post-a-list-or-collection-of-complex-types-with-non-sequential-indices/)

Comment: I changed the model being passed but Step4 comes over as null.

Comment: @ghoston3rd: Please update your changes in your question above. So that i can review it. BTW in your view change this line from  - `@Html.TextBoxFor(val => Model.Step4.DataDetails[i].TextValue, new { @class = "form-control" })` to `@Html.TextBoxFor(val => val.Step4.DataDetails[i].TextValue, new { @class = "form-control" })`

Comment: I've updated the questions with the changes you suggested.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116499/discussion-between-krishnraj-rana-and-ghoston3rd).